# Monkeyrunner/Robotium touch the webview but cannot direct to new page

Tags: android, cordova, robotium, monkeyrunner, android-testing

I've been using Robotium to test on several open source phonegap applications. Recently when I test for [Wikipedia](https://github.com/wikimedia/WikipediaMobile) and [TeamToy-Pocket](https://github.com/easychen/TeamToy-Pocket). I find that Robotium would click on the webElement but will not redirect the screen (while manually click the webElement will do). I've tried two ways of clicking:

```
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.id(id), 1, true);
```

and

```
solo.enterTextInWebElement(By.id(id), text);
```

I observe a click on the designated webElement (using "show pointer location" in developer option), but the expected page transit doesn't happen.

Here's the logcat log when I click the element by Robotium:

```
08-08 12:15:46.044: I/click(16334): Lactarius indigo: uptime: 5003094 realtime: 8755078
08-08 12:15:46.234: D/webview(16334): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
08-08 12:15:56.165: D/DroidGap(16334): Paused the application!
08-08 12:15:56.165: D/CordovaWebView(16334): Handle the pause
08-08 12:15:56.165: D/CordovaWebView(16334): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-08 12:15:56.165: D/WebView(16334): loadUrlImpl: called
08-08 12:15:56.385: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16334): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
08-08 12:15:56.885: D/DroidGap(16334): onDestroy()
08-08 12:15:56.885: D/CordovaWebView(16334): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-08 12:15:56.885: D/WebView(16334): loadUrlImpl: called
08-08 12:15:56.885: D/CordovaWebView(16334): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-08 12:15:56.885: D/WebView(16334): loadUrlImpl: called
```

Then I turned to MonkeyRunner hoping to cope this problem, I use following statement to click a hyperlink

```
device.touch(347,322,MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

and still the same thing, a click was exercised on designated area, but no page transition.

Here's the log when I click the point by MonkeyRunner:

```
08-08 12:18:32.652: V/webview(16574):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE
```

I'm using Galaxy Sumsung S3, and my SDK tool version is 22.0.5. Any suggestion is welcomed.

P.S I also tried monkey using

```
adb shell monkey -p org.wikipedia -v 500 --throttle 500
```

It seems can click on some link and trigger the redirection to the designated page. Don't know why is that.
Thanks!

Comment: You may also try `adb shell input touchscreen tap 347 322` but I guess it's a WebView feature/bug.

Comment: Thanks diego. I thought you mean "adb shell input tap 347 322". That would work.

Comment: Well, that depends on the `input` version, but yes previous versions don't have `touchscreen` or `touchpad` argument.

Comment: ExtSolo should solve your issue (especially clickOnHtmlElement):
http://docs.testdroid.com/_pages/extsolo.html